# Changing OSMDroid's map tile provider back to default

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, osmdroid

In my app, I am setting (online) source of tiles based on user's choice in the preferences (there are only 2 options possible - UMP and default, i.e. OpenStreetMaps). Here is how I change source of the tiles *from* the default:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
if (prefs.getString("map_source_preference", "osm") == "ump") {
    final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(
            getApplicationContext());
    final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("UMP Tiles", null,
            3, 14, 256, ".png", "http://tiles.ump.waw.pl/ump_tiles/");
    tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
    final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider,
            this.getBaseContext());
    mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
}
```

My question is: **how do I set tile provider back to the OSMDroid's default**? Would `tileProvider.detach()` work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to create a new TilesOverlay when you change ITileSource. You can call

```
mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

and that will apply your new tile source to the existing TilesOverlay.

If you wanted to go back to the default tile source you can call

```
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for, but instead I used `mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);` and it worked!

Comment: @RicardoAppleton they are different tile servers with different tiles